# Deserializing List of Dictionary return empty objects

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, entity-framework

I am sending JSON to .NET API.

The backend structure is as this:

```
public class ImportData
{
    public ImportData()
    {
        this.ActionList = new List<ApplicationVersionExecutableActionsDTO>();
        this.ReqList = new List<ApplicationHardwareRequirementsDTO>();
        this.BlockList = new List<ConfiguratorBlocksDTO>();
        this.targetFileErrors = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
    public List<ApplicationVersionExecutableActionsDTO> ActionList { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationHardwareRequirementsDTO> ReqList { get; set; }
    public List<ConfiguratorBlocksDTO> BlockList { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> targetFileErrors { get; set; }
}

public class ImportConflict
{
    public ImportData replaceLists { get; set; }
    public ImportData addLists { get; set; }
    public int appVersionID { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is with `List<Dictionary<string, string>> targetFileErrors` 
I am receiving empty objects.

API Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage ImportResolve(ImportConflict importResolve)
```

Here is how the json looks before sending:

[image: json object]

I'v done something like this several times and I just don't get what is wrong with this one.

JSON not as an image:

```
{
  "replaceLists": {
    "ActionList": [],
    "ReqList": [],
    "BlockList": [],
    "targetFileErrors": [
      {
        "sourceContainer": "da-files-7",
        "targetContainer": "da-files-3",
        "fileName": "appAtract3.xml",
        "$$hashKey": "object:346",
        "resolvedBy": "1"
      },
      {
        "sourceContainer": "da-files-7",
        "targetContainer": "da-files-3",
        "fileName": "appAtract3.js",
        "$$hashKey": "object:347",
        "resolvedBy": "1"
      }
    ],
    "targetAssetErrors": []
  },
  "addLists": {
    "ActionList": [],
    "ReqList": [],
    "BlockList": [],
    "targetFileErrors": [
      {
        "sourceContainer": "da-files-7",
        "targetContainer": "da-files-3",
        "fileName": "CameraInput3.js",
        "$$hashKey": "object:340",
        "resolvedBy": "0"
      },
      {
        "sourceContainer": "da-files-7",
        "targetContainer": "da-files-3",
        "fileName": "FxMill3_x64_644.zip",
        "$$hashKey": "object:341",
        "resolvedBy": "0"
      },
      {
        "sourceContainer": "da-files-7",
        "targetContainer": "da-files-3",
        "fileName": "FxMill-ConfigUpdater-644.zip",
        "$$hashKey": "object:342",
        "resolvedBy": "0"
      },
      {
        "sourceContainer": "da-files-7",
        "targetContainer": "da-files-3",
        "fileName": "init_template3.js",
        "$$hashKey": "object:343",
        "resolvedBy": "0"
      },
      {
        "sourceContainer": "da-files-7",
        "targetContainer": "da-files-3",
        "fileName": "ScreenOutput3.js",
        "$$hashKey": "object:344",
        "resolvedBy": "0"
      },
      {
        "sourceContainer": "da-files-7",
        "targetContainer": "da-files-3",
        "fileName": "AtraTools.zip",
        "$$hashKey": "object:345",
        "resolvedBy": "0"
      }
    ],
    "targetAssetErrors": []
  },
  "appVersionID": 243
}
```

Comment: please post JSON as code block, not image

Comment: Try changing to Dictionary<string, object>.

Comment: added code block. I really don't want to change it to Dictionary<string, object>