# What form of JSON should I use with Dictionary<string,string> in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Usually binding JSON with C# model is pretty simple in Web API, but I found `Dictionary<string, string>` surprisingly tough to work with it.

I have one model, say `Foo`, which has property of type `Bar`:

```
public Bar SomeProp { get; set; }
```

Bar has simple dictionary:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> SomeDict { get; set; }
}
```

Looks simple and when I get this kind of object Web API generates following JSON:

```
"SomeProp": {
              "Bar":       
              {
                "key": "val",
                "key2": "val2"
              }
            }
```

The problem is with reverse thing. When I try to use the same JSON in request Web API doesn't bind it to argument model.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given your type structure, a valid JSON should be `{"SomeProp":{"SomeDict":{"hello":"world"}}}`.

Comment: It doesn't work to me, but maybe problem lies somewhere else in my model. Have you tested it?

Comment: One more thing - you're example is just for one pair, and I can't see how it could be extended to more.

Comment: @Yuval example looks correct. I had the same problem which I never received an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683062/deserializing-list-of-dictionary-return-empty-objects

Comment: I've found the problem. format generated by web API is okay, but there's something I've omitted and haven't posted - non parameter less constructor. Web API has called my constructor with null argument and that was it. Strange was though it haven't thrown any exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to transfer a data container with a property "ExcelRanges" that is a Dictionary. I did not manage to use Dictionary as target type for the property.

As a work around I used a List whose entries consist of a custom class "Range", having a Name and a Values property:

```
/// <summary>
///   Container for data that should be written to an Excel file
/// </summary>
public class ExcelData
{    
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public List<Range> ExcelRanges { get; set; }
}

public class Range
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public List<List<object>> Values { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
[Route("Measures")]
public Guid Measures(ExcelData excelData)
{
 ...
}
```

---

```
function execute(site, filteredMeasures) {

    var excelRanges  = [
     { 
      'Name': 'additionalInvestmentEfficiency', 
      'Values': [[1,2],[3,4]] 
     },
     { 
      'Name': 'totalInvestment', 
      'Values': [[10,20],[30,40]]
     }
   ];

    var data = {
      'Id': site.siteId(),
      'ExcelRanges': excelRanges     
    };

    return $.ajax({
      url: routeConfig.exportMeasureDataByUrl,
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      processData: false,
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: appSecurity.getSecurityHeaders()
    }).done(function(downloadId) {
      window.location.href = routeConfig.exportMeasureDataByUrl + '?downloadId=' + downloadId;
    });


  }
```